Question about reading in dreams
The following question (which I did not ask) has been closed: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/why-we-cant-read-in-dreams
I sometimes lucid dream, and when I do, I notice that I have great difficulty reading.  In fact, this is one way I check if I am indeed dreaming:  when I try to read or write, the words make sense at first and yet start to change to nonsense.
It seems that I am not the only one this has happened to.  See, for example, season 1, episode 30 of Batman: The Animated Series where "Bruce starts to wonder what has happened, especially after seeing the characteristics of a dream (such as book and newspaper prints not making sense) inside this new life."
I personally would like to know any key terms that describe this phenomenon, as it is something that has been depicted in popular media and so most likely has some basis in fact.  (Actually, I have personally experienced it, so I know it is true, at least for me.)  If we ignore the relationship the original poster makes with computers, I think this question is a good one.
I am curious why the question was closed.

You're welcome to join our chat room. The 5 people who voted to close that question are very often in there, you could ask them directly.

It seems that I am not the only one this has happened to. See, for example, season 1, episode 30 of Batman: The Animated Series  Thank you for proving my point so succinctly.

That particular question was problematic for several reasons which should become clear when contrasted with the FAQ, in particular the How To Ask section.
It's up to the asker to point out a hypothesis has some basis in fact. One personal report isn't considered a good question on this site, as it's easily too localized. Therefore we expect the asker to do some background research and at least attempt to frame the question within a scientific framework.
That said, I highly appreciate you taking this to meta as it indicates a will to help out the OP and it also shows more people are interested in the question. If you find it worth salvaging you could try improving it yourself by submitting a suggested edit, taking into account the points mentioned in the FAQ. Additionally it might also be interesting to read through the following two meta posts:

How do I ask a good question?
What level of initial research is expected on questions?

